# Three.js, blender to obj import and LineSegments rendering issues

Tags: three.js, blender

I am exporting a model of a vehicle from blender to an obj file, then importing into three.js. I am able to apply materials to each 'mesh' object by traversing through the loaded object and applying custom materials to all instances of THREE.Mesh as per examples...

However, I can't seem to find a way of doing the same to items that have been exported as type:'LineSegments', these always seem to be drawn as a wireframe... assuming that some kind of conversion is required (either in blender before the export, or inside the three.js loop)...

Anyone managed this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally wrong and in that case, please excuse me, but as far as I know, when you export a model as LineSegments, you explicitly export a wire-frame model.

Materials can only be applied on surfaces (even small ones).

If you want to apply a material to a model, you need to export your model in an other format/type.

Comment: yeah, i would guess that they throw out face definitions when exporting as linesegments, since it would just be taking up space unless you plan to use them, in which case you should export as a normal mesh

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the text of the file exported. You can open it with a text editor and look at it.

See if there is a definition for "faces" anywhere in there. I would guess that linesegments exporter only creates linkages between  vertices, but doesn't define faces - hence no fill, if the file doesn't describe which vertices form faces.

But just look into the text file and make sure there are definitions for more than the vertices, UVs and normals. If there are no face definitions (they'll be sets of 3 integers, ie [12,15,17]), then it is impossible to render faces.

You should try exporting as a normal mesh/geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. I resolved it by opening the .OBJ file and removing any lines starting with "l" (letter L).

In my case, I had a mesh but there were 1 or 2 lines within the shape group; Couldn't find them within the shape group so I remove them from the export.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I changed the format of the exported file from obj to gltf. Hope it helps someone.